# Tagging and Excluding not working for price range in solr

Tags: solr, filter, tagging

Im Using solr 4.10 where i need to add tagging and excluding filters in price range facet where the below Query is not working

```
select?&q=fasttrack&fl=catentry_id,price_INR&facet=true&facet.field=price_INR&facet.query=price_INR:(*%2015)&facet.query=price_INR:({0%201000}%201000)&facet.query=price_INR:({1000%202000}%202000)&facet.query=price_INR:({2000%203000}%203000)&facet.query=price_INR:({3000%204000}%204000)&facet.query=price_INR:({5000%20*})&fq={!tag=p}price_INR:({*%201000}%201000)&facet.field={!ex=p}price_INR
```

Can Anyone please help me on this?

Comment: I'd think you'd need to your exclusion for each `facet.query`? Could you try `facet.query={!ex=p}price_INR...` for each `facet.query`?

Comment: Even if i add facet.query for each price range the count is still zero.only for the selected tag it is showing count, for other price ranges the count is stillzero(even though the value is there)

Comment: But have you added the exclusion for each query?

Comment: ya ya i added and tried but still zero results